# I'm using typescript and trying to create a connection using createConnection(({}).then(()); there are errors with .then

Tags: mysql, typescript

I am very new to macOS and I am following along to a course and I am stuck on trying to make a mysql connection.
The error I am getting is:
Property 'then' does not exist on type '{ type: string; host: string; port: number; username: string; password: string; database: string; entities: sting[]; logging: boolean; synchronizer: boolean; }'

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import {routes} from "./routes";
import { createConnection } from 'net';

createConnection(({
    type: "mysql",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 8000,
    username: "admin",
    password: "admin-1",
    database: "FirstDB",
    entities: [
        "src/entity/*.ts"
    ],
    logging: false,
    synchronize: true,
}).then(() => { 

    const app = express();

    app.use(express.json());

    app.use(cors());

    routes(app);

    app.listen(8000, () => {
        console.log('listening to port 8000')
    });
}));
```

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#netcreateconnection

Comment: thank you for answering. Please excuse my naivety but why is there a net. before createConnection? I am not using that convention.

Comment: The 'net' in 'net.createConnection' is a module loaded into the current file with a import or require statement, eg const net = require('net');. As you are only calling one function in the module, you are ok to just import that function instead of the whole module, which is what you are doing with import { createConnection } from 'net'

Comment: Got it. Thanks Matt. Question - in the link provided above I dont see an example or documentation on how to handle the .then error I am getting.

Comment: The `createConnection` is not async, so it doesn't return a Promise (which is "thenable") but a net.Socket. You need to pass a second parameter, the callback that will be added as a listener for the 'connect' event on the returned socket once.

Comment: Matteo - I took some time and tried to rewrite the code. No luck. I guess I still am missing some of the basics I guess. My code is listening for port 8000. Any chance you can point me to an example having used import createConnections from net?

Comment: I suggest you to change the net package in favour of https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql and give it a try.

Comment: sure thing. thanks.